# GROUP BY one variable but display multiple SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to GROUP BY one categorical variable but also show another corresponding variable in my output in SQL. Here is what the table looks  like:[Original Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E90sy.png)

There are three main variables I'm working with here: Game, Platform and Week. Week variable states the position of the game under the global charts, so 1 would mean its the number 1 game. I want to find the game with the most weeks inside the top 10 BY platform, so I'm trying to get my table to look like this:
Platform | Game | Most_weeks_top10

Right now, I tried the following steps:
`SELECT platform, game, COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM global_weekly_charts_2013_2014 
WHERE week <= 10 
GROUP BY game, platform;`

Which returns this:
[Table Grouped By Platform AND Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZBj2.png)

However, I only want the game, platform and total weeks of the game with *max* number of weeks in top 10. I tried

`SELECT game, platform, Max(total) OVER (PARTITION BY platform)` 
from the derived table but did not get the desired output. I feel like the solution is right there and not that difficult but I can't seem to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

please add “ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10”.try again

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't give the answer in the desired format, it just returns the top 10 totals, not the max of each platform and game